# Uniform continuity of 2 variable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x,t)$ be a continous function of $x$ for every $c\le t\le d$ and a continuous function of $t$ for every $a\le x\le b$. Let the partial derivative $\frac{\delta f}{\delta t}$ and $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}$ exist for every $x$ and $t$ in the above intervals. How can I prove that:

$\forall t_0,\varepsilon:$ there exist $\Delta t$ such that $\forall x,t:a\le x\le b,|t-t_0|<\Delta t$

$$|f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)|<\varepsilon$$